# How to calculate the area of an asteroid using Green's theorem

Tags: area, greens-theorem

I came across this question in my revision:
Use Green's theorem to calculate the area of an asteroid defined by $x=\cos^3{t}$ and $y=\sin^3{t}$ where $0\leqslant t \leqslant 2\pi$ . The question gives a hint by saying that the area of the asteroid is $\iint \,dx\,dy$.
I interpreted this tip to be that $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 1$$ but then got stuck from there. I know the final answer is meant to be $\frac{3\pi a^2}{8}$. Would really appreciate a tip or a correction of the first step?
For reference, Greens theorem: $$\oint_C (P\,dx+Q\,dy)=\iint_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y})\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: This curve is called an [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).

Answer (score 2):

You can take
$$ Q = -\frac{1}{2}x, \qquad P = \frac{1}{2}y, $$
and then the area is
$$ \iint_R dx \, dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_C (-y \, dx + x \, dy). $$
Parametrise this and do the calculation and you should get the right answer.

This formula can actually be rephrased in polar coordinates to be more transparent:
$$  -y \, dx + x \, dy = -r\sin{\theta} (\cos{\theta} \, dr -r\sin{\theta} \, d\theta ) + r\cos{\theta}(\sin{\theta}\, dr + r\cos{\theta} \, d\theta) = r^2 \, d\theta,  $$
the area of a sector of the circle of radius $r$ with angle $d\theta$.

Comment: but wait, $\frac{\partial Q}{\partial X}$ and the same for P would be zero? that wouldn't satisfy the initial tip?

Comment: Hang on, I've got them the wrong way round...

Comment: Perfect, just wanted to check!

Comment: Also, could I use any values for Q and P that satisfy the initial condition or is it just these? If it is just these, why  and how did you pick them? Ease?

Comment: This has nice symmetry, and an interpretation in polar coordinates. You can choose anything so that the appropriate derivatives add up to $1$.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Just revising for first year exams and hadn't gone over Green's in a while...

Comment: It's just a bit of a bitch of an integral but got it in the end! Thanks again